# About operator "x" in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I am confused by the following output of the code:

```
print "1234567890" x (10+9)/10;
```

The output is

```
1.23456789012346e+188.
```

I know the code should be this in order to get the intended result:

```
"1234567890" x ((10+9)/10)
```

But why does the former code generate a float number but not a string? Isn't the operator "x" a string operator in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x is a string operator, but you are using / on the string it produces, which numifies "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678912345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" and divides it by 10.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's see what perl treats that expression as using the [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) module:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'print "1234567890" x (10+9)/10;'
print((3993258840062839 * 2**573));
```

Obviously it's evaluating it as a number. Maybe because of the division? Let's try taking that out.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'print "1234567890" x (10+9);'
print('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890');
```

which looks about right. So, basically, it's printing out that number because you're treating that really long string as a number thanks to the division.

Note that `x` and `/` have the same precedence, and are left associative, so that `a x b / c` is treated as `(a x b) / c`.

Answer (score 5):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity

`x` and `/` have the same precedence. So

```
print "1234567890" x (10+9)/10;
```

is equivalent to

```
print(  ("1234567890" x (10+9)) / 10  );
```

Note that `x` is not only a string repetion operator. It can generate lists: `(1) x 3` is `(1, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `1234467890` is concat'd 19 times, then divided by 10 which creates a float.